# JPQL for generating histogram

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to form a query to generate histogram of following.

Assume entity Animal, with unbounded number of Tags.

```
dog.features = [blue, big, fury, nice]
cat.features = [white, big, fury, ugly]
bear.features = [white, big, fury, ugly]
other_bear.features = [white, big, fury, ugly]
```

Imagine I will want to generate histogram of counts of similar features of cat and others.

Firstly, we need counts of similar features for all couples with cat

```
 similar_features(cat, dog) = 2
 similar_features(cat, bear) = 4
 similar_features(cat, other_bear) = 4
```

Then, the histogram of similar features would be:

```
|0| = 0
|1| = 0
|2| = 1
|3| = 0
|4| = 2
```

I would like to achieve this with JPQL - I started like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT feature1) cnt, COUNT(COUNT(DISTINCT feature1)) 
 FROM Animal a1, Animal a2 
 JOIN a1.features feature1 JOIN a2.features feature2 
 WHERE feature1 = feature2 AND i2.id = ?1 
 GROUP BY a1, cnt
```

This is obviously wrong, but it is showing what I am trying to achieve. Is this even possible with JPQL?